# Why is global-auto-revert-mode not reverting my buffer?

Tags: emacs, revert

`global-auto-revert-mode` sometimes doesn't revert my buffers.  These are regular files (source code), and this happens most often when messing around in source control (e.g. stashing changes, rolling back to an earlier version, the updating and un-stashing).

Edit: After further investigation, emacs v. 24.5 is using libgio to get notifications of file changes, but some notifications are getting dropped: `file-notify-callback` isn't called for some of my files.  Perhaps a buffer somewhere is overflowing when so many files are changed at once?

Comment: You may be running into some of the issues mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512086/emacs-reverts-buffer-to-weird-previous-state-with-git-rebase.

Comment: @DewayneChristensen Thanks!  In my case, when I go to edit the file, emacs tells me that the version on disk is different what's in the buffer.  So, one part of emacs can tell the difference, I'm not sure why the rest can't.

Comment: Workaround: set `auto-revert-use-notify` to `nil`.

Comment: For newer version of emacs: `(setq auto-revert-verbose nil)`